# Formato para mostrar respuesta de Query en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quisiera saber si hay una manera de obtener las dos últimas semanas y sus cantidades en SQL, me explico:

La siguiente consulta me trae las dos últimas semanas con sus cantidades de un mismo producto así:

```
$first        = strtotime('last Monday -14 days');
$last         = strtotime('next Sunday -7 days');
$dateInitial  = date('Y-m-d', $first);
$dateFinal    = date('Y-m-d', $last);

SELECT "pr_products.product,
       WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date) AS week, 
       SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS quantity
FROM   pf_harvest
       INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
WHERE  pf_harvest.date BETWEEN ".$dateInitial." AND ".$dateFinal."
       AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
       AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
GROUP BY product, WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date)";
```

El resultado que me da es el siguiente:

```
-------------------------------------
product     |    week  |   quantity |
-------------------------------------
ROSA PINK   |    33    |    1076000 |
-------------------------------------
ROSA PINK   |    34    |    1094025 |
-------------------------------------
```

Que está bien, el problema es que quiero que el resultado de la consulta me quede algo así:

```
-------------------------------------
product     |    week1 |   week2    |
-------------------------------------
ROSA PINK   |  1076000 |    1094025 |
-------------------------------------
```

Paso las fechas de la siguiente manera:

Esto con el fin de obtener las cantidades de tanto la semana 33 como la 34 agrupado en un mismo producto. No sé si es posible hacerlo de esta manera, lo que no quiero es jugar con el Javascript para mostrar los resultados.

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos (y versión) estás ocupando?

Comment: Estoy usando MySQL Versión 5.5 @Lamak

Comment: cómo pasas las fechas?, a través de variables?

Comment: si por variables, ya edite la pregunta para que veas como las obtengo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes tratar usando tu consulta actual como una tabla derivada, y haciendo una nueva agregación sobre ésta:

```
"SELECT T.product,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T.week = WEEKOFYEAR(".$dateInitial.") THEN quantity END) week1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T.week = WEEKOFYEAR(".$dateFinal.") THEN quantity END) week2
FROM (  SELECT pr_products.product,
               WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date) AS week, 
               SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM   pf_harvest
               INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
        WHERE  pf_harvest.date BETWEEN ".$dateInitial." AND ".$dateFinal."
               AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
               AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
        GROUP BY product, WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date)) AS T
GROUP BY T.product";
```

Comment: Si funcionó, muchas gracias! que bien :)